# Update a custom list with workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

we use Sharepoint Online and we have created a custom list to show spare stock in our business.  The custom list contains (amongst other things) a column for 'Reserved By' and a column for 'Sold To'. Both of these columns contain person/group lookup data. What we would like to do is:

1. Once a user enters their name in the 'Reserved By' field they should receive an email with the details of their reservation. We have successfully tested this by using Sharepoint Designer workflow.
2. After 4 days, if that reserved stock is not sold (ie, the 'Sold To' field is still blank) then the 'Reserved By' field is cleared and that stock item can be reserved by someone else.
3. If the 'Reserved By' and 'Sold To' fields are populated within 4 days then take no action.

Can anyone help with explaining the easiest way to accomplish this? Our initial attempts of creating a workflow in Sharepoint Designer to carry out step 2 has resulted in failure!  This is almost certainly because we have had no training with SPD and we're grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do a New Item workflow and add a pause timer for 4 days.  Once the 4 days expires have the workflow put the value of the field in a workflow variable so that you can check the field for null/not null.  Then have the workflow check the variable to see if it is empty.  Update the current item for the reserved by field accordingly.  You do have to use the update item action and not the set field in current item action to do this.  Screen shot below so you can see the basic setup.

[image]

Comment: Hello Nate, thank you so much.  It works!  We realised that we needed to make sure that the 'Reserved By' field had something in it so we made the following change:

Comment: Hello Nate, thank you so much.  It works!  We realised that we needed to make sure that the 'Reserved By' field had something in it so we made the following change: we added a variable for the Reserved By field and checked that it wasn't empty.  Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad it worked out!