# How to setup SharePoint Workflow to email a person in people picker field?

Tags: 2013, designer

I am trying to setup a workflow in SharePoint Designer that will email to a value (person) entered to a people picker field. By default that field is blank. 
Once that field is populated I want that person to receive email with a hyperlink to edit that form. I am talking about a Custom List here. Thanks!

Every time the Designer is trying to tie that value to "these users" asking to select from a list, but my goal is for the system to email that person (from Active Directory) that someone will enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a change workflow and store the value of the lookup field in a workflow variable.  Create an IF condition to look at the variable to detect when it is not empty.  Create an email action and in the To field do a lookup to the person field.

Update:  You can look at a previous post of mine to see a screen shot.  It's similar to what you're trying to accomplish in that it is trying to execute an action based on a person lookup field having a value.

[Update a custom list with workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208056/update-a-custom-list-with-workflow/208089#208089)

To do the lookup to send to the person in the lookup field (below is using the Created By field but works the same for custom people lookup fields):

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I believe, this is a bit complicated to understand with my experience. Could you be so kind and outline some details step-by-step? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Updated my response with a link to a previous post which is similar to what you are trying to do.  Not sure if that's enough detail to get you where you need to be.  Let me know if you have any questions.